# Is $P\{X_1\leq \alpha- X_2\leq X_2\}=F_{X_1}(\alpha)\left[1-F_{X_2}(\frac{\alpha}{2})\right]$?.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ two independent random variables with CDF 
$F_{X_1}(x_1)$ and $F_{X_2}(x_2)$.

Can we say or it is true  that
$$P\{X_1\leq \alpha- X_2\leq X_2\}=P\{X\leq \alpha\leq 2X_2\}$$

$$P\{X_1\leq \alpha\leq 2X_2\}=F_{X_1}(\alpha)\left[1-F_{X_2}(\frac{\alpha}{2})\right]$$.

Thanks

Comment: What is $X$? You are given $X_1$ and $X_2$ but there is no $X$ here.

Comment: Hi, yes I am sorry I forget it is $X_1$

Comment: hi I am try to avoiding something like that $F_{x_i}(\alpha-x_i).$

Comment: because in my PDFs and CDFs, for example  if I use $\int_{x_1=0}^{\alpha}f_{X_1}(x_1)F_{X_2}(\alpha-x_1)$

Comment: You cannot use densities unless you are told that the given random variables have densities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are wrong . For the first one $X_1=1,X_2=2$ and $\alpha =2$ gives a counterexample. For the second one you need continuity of $F_{X_2}$ at the point $\frac {\alpha} 2$. In general you should take the left hand limit of $F_{X_2}$ at the point $\frac {\alpha} 2$ on RHS.

Comment: So it probability zero?

Comment: Yes, in my example LHS is $0$ but  RHS is $1$.

Comment: So there cases where is not zero or it alwas zeros ($X_1\leq \alpha-X_2$ and $\alpha-X_2\leq X_2$) so we can not express using CDF,?

Comment: $X_1 \leq \alpha -X_2$ means $X_1+X_2 \leq \alpha$ so you have to carry out an an integration over a suiatble subset of $\mathbb R^{2}$ w.r.t. the joint distribution.

Comment: Can I modifies this question to put all my problem or I add new question, because first I was find diffuct to slove this probability $P\{X_1+X_2\leq \alpha, X_1\leq X_2\}$.

Comment: $P\{X_1+X_2\leq \alpha, X_1\leq X_2\}=$P\{X_2\leq \alpha-X_1, X_1\leq X_2\}=\int_{x_1=0}^{\alpha/2}f_{X_1}(x_1)$

Comment: $P\{X_1+X_2 \leq \alpha, X_1 \leq X_2\}=\int_{(-\infty, \alpha /2]} (F_{X_2}(\alpha-x_1)-F_{X_2}(x_1-))dF_{X_1}$.

Comment: Yes I agree with you but when I use this equation I get something like $\int_{0}^{\alpha/2}e^{-x_1( \beta_1(n_2+1)-\beta_2n_2)} $ where $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are parameter of $X_1$ and $X_2$. Now this integral need condition that $\beta_1(n_2+1)-\beta_2n_2\neq 0$ and also we can not use for random variable that $\beta_1=\beta_2$. actually $X_1$ and $X_2$ that I use $X_1 $ is the maximum of $N_1$ gamma random variable with parameter $\beta_1$ and  $X_2$ is the maximum of $N_2$ gamma random variable with parameter $\beta_2$. So I am try to avoiding $\alpha-x_1$

Comment: So I use the following solution

Comment: If you have specific distributions in mind you can ask a separate question or modify this question. My answer is for the most general case.

Comment: Ok I will prepare my question and I will put it. Thank you So much. I will do that tomorrow because is 1.14 in my country.  Have nice end day.

Comment: But I think the above probability is zero for all positive value or positive random variable?

Comment: Find $P\{\{X_1+X_2\leq \alpha\}\cap\{X_1\leq X_2\}\}$ for $X_1$ have same parameter or different parameter
    URL:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3263304.